# Beamer, columns, and movie positionning bug

Tags: beamer, columns, multimedia

I'm trying to put in beamer a movie in a two columns document, and center it. However, I found a strange bug that I'm not able to solve.

Here is the output I get:

[image]

And here is the output I want:

[image]

I tried to use something like `\vspace*{-0.2\textheight}`, it works to center the picture, but then when I play the movie, the movie is not centered anymore...

Any idea?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}     
\usepackage{multimedia}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Me}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}

    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
      \movie[height = 0.8\textheight, width = \textwidth, showcontrols]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{Videos/qubit_presentation_0001.png}}{Videos/qubit_presentation.mp4}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and the png used:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You image (and I assume also your video) looks more or less quadratic, but with using `0.8\textheight` you reserve basically the whole height of the page for it, on the same time you give it about half the page as width, so the image/video will shrink down and occupy only the bottom part of the space you reserved for it.

Try a height more similar to the width, for example `height = \textwidth`.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}     
\usepackage{multimedia}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Me}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
      \movie[height = \textwidth, width = \textwidth, showcontrols]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{Xj8Xv}}{test}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]